# Infer interface key-specific value type without using Generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

In the following code snippet
I have a simple lookup function, which looks into an object, and returns object[key] value

```
interface Bar {  
  abc: string;  
  def: boolean;  
}  

// Without generics - Case I
function lookup(data: Bar, key: keyof Bar) {
  return data[key];
}

// With generics - Case II
function lookup<K extends keyof Bar>(data: Bar, key: K) {
  return data[key];
}

const someData: Bar = {
  abc: 'abinash',
  def: true
};

type abcType = 'abc';
let x = lookup(someData, 'abc' as abcType); // output - string | boolean instead of only string
// here I am trying to explicity pass that the key value is of type 'abc' to allow inferring as Bar['abc'], same as with generics,
```

With generics, TS is able to infer the type of corresponding key lookup because
lookup(someData, 'abc') is equivalent to lookup<'abc'>(someData, 'abc')
and hence, 'abc' is replaced with the generic mentions
As lookup ReturnType is Bar[K] transforms into Bar['abc'], and TS is able to tell me correctly the type of Bar['abc'] for my function call

Without generics, the return type of lookup is constrainted to string | boolean via default type computation.

Is there anyway possible to infer the type without using generics ?
(This is a limitation and encouraging more usage of generics for better type specificity in certain cases)

Comment: Generics are a very important part of the language, some things can't be expressed without them. This is one of them. I would not call it a limitation, this is just the way to express that the type of the output is tied to specific type of the input passed in. Also `lookup(someData, 'abc')` is sufficient, `K` will be inferred to `'abc'` no need for the cast

Comment: Personally, I think adding generics to the function definition is a perfectly fine price for the extra specificity you claim to want. I also would not call this a limitation.